# How to run .sql file in PySpark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am able to run a single SQL query using PySpark. For example

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appNmae("___").getOrCreate()
df = spark.sql("select * from ...")
```

But I have a .sql file full of many queries that I want to run. Do I have to execute them one at a time individually, or is there an easy way to run all of them?

Example:
3 rows, 3 columns in table1 and same in table2

.sql file

```
select * from table1;

select * from table2;
```

Output df:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
3  a  b  c
4  d  e  f
5  g  h  i
```

or

df1

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

and df2

```
   A  B  C
0  a  b  c
1  d  e  f
2  g  h  i
```

Comment: Does it have to be with PySpark? What are you really trying to do? You can execute queries from the command line `hive -f my file.sql`. (`hive` may be deprecated but there's some equivalent way to do this)

Comment: Ideally I want to save all the results of the queries, for example to a dataframe (one big one ideally but even one for each) or csv.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with two small queries and the desired output?

Comment: Update on my original commend: Hive is deprecated but you can use `beeline -f myfile.sql` [Beeline Hive Commands](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-BeelineCommands). (though based on the clarifications, this likely doesn't answer your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine all query results into a list of dataframes (assuming each line is one single query)

```
with open('/path/to/file.sql', 'r') as f:
    query = f.readlines()

dfs = []
for line in query:
    dfs.append(spark.sql(line))
```

If you want to combine all dataframes (assuming that they all have the same schema)

```
from functools import reduce

df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), dfs)
```

Comment: This is not a well written question. One could potentially read the file and split on `;` but that's not guaranteed to work either. What if there are comments? What if the `;` character appears in a string? What if one query fails? I don't think there's going to be an easy/clean solution to the general case unless you want to implement your own query interpreter.

Comment: @pault that's true, but I guess this is an MVP for the question's purpose... at least it works for the simple example in the question